# UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentType:in) deprecated in iOS 14

Tags: swiftui, ios14

I am developing a swiftUI iOS 13+ application and I ran into a warning while developing a UIViewRepresentable for document picking.

According to the apple dev doc the initialiser of UIDocumentPickerViewController will be deprecated in future releases so this line:

```
let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypePDF as String], in: .open)
```

promts a deprecation warning and I have troubles finding a replacement. Can somebody help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While asking the question I noticed there was other initialisers to this class. I ended up just using the :

```
UIDocumentPickerViewControllerinit(forOpeningContentTypes: [UTType])
```

convenience initializer

I let this answer here since the function just became deprecated and no google search showed any answers less than a year old.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

> let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [UTType.png,UTType.jpeg, UTType.pdf],asCopy: true)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
let supportedTypes = [UTType.audio]
let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes)
```